# jQuery required( dependency-expression ) is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using jquery [validation](http://plugins.jquery.com/validation/) plugin. When I was using required( dependency-expression ) i noticed that 
[required( dependency-expression )](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) are not working properly. as mentioned that i tried for

```
$("#flight_availability").validate({
    rules: { 
       Trip: { required: true },
       DepartDate: { required : "#OneTrip:checked" },
       Origin: { required:"#OriginId:blank" }
    },
});
```

In the above mentioned code the code `DepartDate: { required : "#OneTrip:checked" },` works fine but `Origin: { required:"#OriginId:blank" }` does not work.

Whats wrong with the code? I used firebug. It did not show any errors. even used validation debug option too, but :(

Comment: can you share the markup also

Comment: it seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F9PFP/2/

Comment: can you share html for `OriginId` and `Origin`

Comment: @ArunPJohny try to add some random text in `<input id='Origin' name='Origin'/>` and test then, even if `OriginId` is empty(blank), it validates it as true

Comment: That is what the rules is saying, it says if `OriginId` is blank `Origin` is required. It doesn't say that if `OriginId` is blank then should be left blank

Comment: @ArunPJohny, what i understand is `required:"#OriginId:blank"` should evaluate true only when `OriginId` is blank(empty). But when I enter some text in `<input id='Origin' name='Origin'/>` then it does not check, is still `OriginId` is blank or not. is it so?

Comment: What's so hard to understand?  Your rule is saying `Origin` field is _only_ required when the `#OriginId` field is empty.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: @Sparky his rule definition and what he wants are different

Comment: I don't think there is a build in rule for that purpose

Comment: @Sparky is there a rule to validate something like `Field x should be blank` ie opposite of `required`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, he has to clearly explain what he wants and a custom method can be written.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, ohhh, if that's what he wants I'll have to search my old answers.  I did one like this recently.

Comment: @Sparky yes that is right, that is what I was trying to get from him using the above comments

Comment: @Sparky Still I'm not sure that is what he wants, looks like our assumption is right, but he has to confirm

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I found it... it's possible.

Comment: @Sparky is there a existing method or a custom one you wrote

Comment: @Sparky what I want is mentioned below your ans. Please have a look

Comment: Guys, here it is what I want Hello guys. Ok I am wrong. what my scenario is I am using jquery auto-complete for Origin destination select. just to confirm selected destination is correct, i store OriginId integer value in hidden element OriginId when select origin from autocomplere drop down list. Ok then what I want is at validation time is OriginId is only set if valid origin is selected. So if OriginId is empty means Origin value (anything) is invalid. I need to do like this. What should I do? Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's comments:

> *"even if OriginId is empty(blank), it validates it as true"*

Yes, that is exactly how you programmed it.

```
Origin: {
    required: "#OriginId:blank"
}
```

The above code is saying that the `Origin` field is only `required` when the `#OriginId` field is left blank.  Using `#OriginId:filled`, this logic is saying that the `Origin` field must remain empty if the `#OriginId` is filled in.  If that's not exactly correct, then you can use the `:blank` selector instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/xMAs5/

If you want the opposite behavior then use the `:filled` selector instead.

```
Origin: {
    required: "#OriginId:filled"
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xMAs5/1/

---

Otherwise, here is a demo using a custom method called `empty` that works as per your comment: *"So if `OriginId` is empty means `Origin` value (anything) is invalid."*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod('empty', function (value, element) {
        return (value === '');
    }, "This field must remain empty!");

    $("#flight_availability").validate({
        rules: {
            Trip: {
                required: true
            },
            DepartDate: {
                required: "#OneTrip:checked"
            },
            Origin: {
                empty: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#OriginId").is(":blank")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ab8bT/**

Comment: I think we want the Origin to be entered only if OriginId also is entered

Comment: there is a minor bug in the rule related to checking the dependency rule http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xMAs5/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, yes, I was fiddling around, but eventually got it working.  Must use the `depends` sub-rule and `.is(':blank')`.  I like your version too which also seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the jQuery puesdo selector try using :empty instead of :blank.

Comment: Sam, see the documentation please.  `:blank` is a perfectly valid selector:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Custom_selectors